# how to run scala jar file within java file?

Tags: java, scala

I need to run Scala jar file from Java code:

So, if I had this Scala code:

```
object test extends App {
    override def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world! " + args.toList)
    }
}
```

and I exported in `demo.jar`, I want to execute from inside Java application?
The way I'm using it is to throw runtime process, which not working with me?

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class testscalajar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"scala","-cp","d:\\demo.jar", "test"});
            // Then retrieve the process output
            InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
            String inString = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF8"); 
            String errString = IOUtils.toString(err, "UTF8"); 
            System.out.println(inString);
            System.out.println(errString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody have any other solutions?????

Comment: Please, please don't do this. That compiled Scala code is JVM bytecode, and it's pretty easy to use it as such from Java (especially if you're using a JVM build tool with Scala support, which is most of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala compiles down to ordinary JVM `.class` files, you don't need any external processes to use Scala code from Java or Java code from Scala.

Make sure that your path settings are correct, then simply create Scala objects and call Scala methods from your Java code as if it were just yet another Java library.

Comment: @chiva `App.main(new String[] { "test" })` or whatever—exactly what you'd do if `App` was a Java class.

Comment: You make sure that the right `jar`s are on your classpath, you make sure that you `import yourpackage.App;` in you Java code, then you simply call the main `App.main(new String[]{})`. However, you probably would not want to call it main. What build tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using eclips with scala IDE support

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE, not a build-tool per se. However, it should have  `Project -> Dependencies -> Add External Jars` or something like that. So you open your java-project, add the "scala-jar" that contains your compiled scala code, add all the required scala libraries as well (that's where a build tool like `SBT` would come handy) and just use it as if it were "java-jar" (although there is actually no difference between "java-jars" and "scala-jars", it's all just JVM bytecode).